# Using a route to return 408 on a specific file name request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

We have an issue whereby Outlook is misbehaving because it is attempting to read an `autodiscover.xml` on our domain, specifically `https://example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`.

The email host says that we should configure the websitefirewall to return a timeout error.  However, the site is hosted on Azure, and I don't see any option to do that.

Therefore, I was wondering if this could be done in MVC?  I tried the following:

```
public class AutoDiscoverController : Controller
{
    [Route("autodiscover/autodiscover.xml")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout);
    }
}
```

...but it doesn't work; I see a 404 page instead.  A breakpoint on the method also never gets hit.

Is it possible to create a route that mimics a non-existent file to return the timeout error?

#### Duplicate question update

There is a similar question at [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis).  However, this question differs in that:

- The answer doesn't work in MVC5
- I cannot create a rule to recognise a trailing slash in the URL, because Outlook is generating the URL and I have no control over that

#### What else I've tried...

1. In RouteConfig, I defined a custom route.  It doesn't work; the route never gets hit.

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
               name: "AutoDiscover",
               url: "autodiscover/autodiscover.xml",
               defaults: new { controller = "AutoDiscover", action = "Index" });
   ```
2. As above, but using `url: "autodiscover/*"`
3. `routes.IgnoreRoute("autodiscover.xml");`
4. Defined a Route attribute on the controller itself, then enable `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

Comment: Can you blacklist the IP of your exchange server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: @NightOwl888 no problem thanks.  I worked through that answer and provided an update above

Comment: @EvilDr you are using attribute routing but I see no indication that you enabled  it `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`. Making sure it is registered before convention-based routes.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks.  I added it in, but the route/controller still doesn't get hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer, thanks to Rick Strahl's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33717969/792888), and [related blog post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Nov/13/Serving-URLs-with-File-Extensions-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application).

For some reason, defining a route in the RouteConfig never hits, but doing it at controller level *does* work.  However, an additional step is needed, as pointed out by Nkosi to get it to work.

#### 1. Enable MVC Attribute Routing

This wires up the routing attributes at controller-level (done in the next step)

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); // <-- Added this

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

#### 2. Add the Route as an attribute

```
public class AutoDiscoverController : Controller
{
    [Route("autodiscover/autodiscover.xml")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Configure a route based on specific files in web.config

I believe this forces MVC to take over what IIS would usually handle (as XML is considered a *"static"* file).

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />

    <!-- Added this line -->
    <add name="AutoDiscoverXmlFileHandler" path="autodiscover.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />

  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

#### Result

[image]