# Check if Appium server is up and ready

Tags: c#, port, appium

I wrote a code that start Appium server and after I start some automation.
This is the Appium Launch code: (in C#)

using System.Diagnostics;

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process;
process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized; //Change to Hidden after debug
startInfo.FileName = AppiumNodePath;
startInfo.Arguments =   AppiumJSPath + " --address " + AppiumServerIP + " --port " + currentAppiumPort + " --automation-name Appium --log-no-color --session-override --log C:\\test\\AppiumLog.txt";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I want to wait for Appium Server to be ready and only then to start the automation, Because if you start creating driver before I get an exception that Appium port is busy/refused.

**How can I check if Appium is up and ready?**

Comment: Well, one option would be to try and connect, catch the error, wait and then retry.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a call to `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/sessions` this will return all running sessions. You then get an xml response with the session information.

Comment: what do you mean by "make a call"?

Comment: Refer to this link, you need to make an HTTP request to the link I described above:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688350/c-sharp-how-to-make-a-http-call

Comment: Thanks for your comment, when I try - GetResponse() I get "System.Net.WebException:  The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found" Exception. Do you know why?

Comment: I would need your appium logs to be able to diagnose. I would assume that you are on a different port or are using the `http://0.0.0.0:4723` URL

Comment: Also make sure you have the plural for the `/sessions` I believe if you forget the `s` at the end you will get a 404

Comment: I will add here Appium Logs, where do you think that I have the "session" instead of "sessions" mistake?

Answer (score -1):

Run this command in the terminal:

```
appium &
```

Comment: this is the command to start in background and doesnt answer the question at all