# HTTP request for Github API

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, github

I'm developing a web application in C# to search for users with Github accounts but I have no idea how to start it. 
I don't want to use a framework like Octokit. I want to call everything in c#.

How do you link the API with the search box in HTML?

Comment: I'm trying to use the Github API to get it to work. But I don't know how search. So I've setup the search box. But how do I get what's being searched to use the API? I'm guessing I need to get the search query into the url https://api.github.com/users/{user}? But how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [C# web request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7688458/2027146) to call the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

Example:

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/repos/screaminghawk/phone-saver/issues?state=closed");
WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: But how do I use a make the search bar search for that information? I'm used to PHP and C# is just going over my head at the minute. I've already got the UI of the app sorted it's just the seever side code I'm struggling with.